# Getting single message from Graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a single email from an Office 365 Mailbox.

I'm sending the email `id` to my app via a POST (`req.body.id`) and then calling this code in order to get some email properties:

```
router.post('/id', async function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("email with ID -> ", req.body.id)
    let parms = { title: 'Inbox', active: { inbox: true } };
    const accessToken = await authHelper.getAccessToken(req.cookies, res);
    const userName = req.cookies.graph_user_name;

    if (accessToken && userName) {
    parms.user = userName;
    // Initialize Graph client
    const client = graph.Client.init({
        authProvider: (done) => {
        done(null, accessToken);
        }
    });

    try {
        const result = await client
        .api('/me/messages/', req.body.id)
        .select('id,subject,from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,body,sentDateTime,receivedDateTime')
        .get();

        parms.messages = result.value;
        console.log("email -> ", result.value);
        res.render('message', parms);

    } catch (err) {
        parms.message = 'Error retrieving messages';
        parms.error = { status: `${err.code}: ${err.message}` };
        parms.debug = JSON.stringify(err.body, null, 2);
        res.render('error', parms);
        }

    } else {
    // Redirect to home
    res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

At the moment, `result.value` contains all of the messages in the mailbox instead of just the message with provided `id`.

Could someone tell me where my error is, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `api` method has a single path parameter. Calling it like `.api('/me/messages/', req.body.id)` is effectivly sending it a path ("/me/messages/") along with an additional parameter it ignores.

You need to send it a single string so you'll need to append the `req.body.id` to the path (`{path} + {id}`):

```
const result = await client
  .api('/me/messages/' + req.body.id)
  .select('id,subject,from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,body,sentDateTime,receivedDateTime')
  .get();
```